# Добавление собственных провайдеров учетных записей в Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7

Приобрел недавно девайс на базе Windows Phone 8, и заметил интересную вещь. 
В системных настроках есть возможность привязки различных учетных записей - Windows Live, Twitter, Facebook, Skype для последующей синхронизации контактов и прочего.
Также на телефонах от Nokia (под управление Windows Phone 7.5) есть возможность подключения учетных записей Nokia, и T-Mobile (телефон куплен в Германии). Выглядит это примерно так:

[image: скриншот]

Каким образом можно добавить сюда собственный провайдер для последующей сихронизации контактов?

Покопавшись на MSDN нашел упоминание о возможности создания [Contact Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207034(v=vs.105).aspx) для своего приложения, с возможностью отображения контактов в общем, системном списке. Но там ни слова о системной странице настроек! С примерами тоже крайне скудно.

Может кто-то сталкивался?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно, в Windows Phone 8 приложение может создавать и изменять свои собственные  контакты. Эти контакты впоследствии видны в People Hub. При этом вы можете управлять, будут ли доступны контакты для редактирования в People Hub, а также могут ли другие приложения читать полную информацию о контактах.

"Добавлять" такие приложения с собственными контактами из страницы настроек нельзя.

По поводу примеров — вот тут есть базовые примеры:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207024(v=vs.105).aspx

Хорошие и полные примеры работы с контактами есть в этой книге:

[Windows Phone 8 Development Internals](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145373342.do)

Comment: огромное спасибо за книгу!

Comment: Не за что. Она еще в процессе написания, финальная версия выйдет в феврале. Но купив ее сейчас, все апдейты к ней будут бесплатны.